# SLatex and line numbering?

Tags: line-numbering

I'm using [SLaTeX](http://evalwhen.com/slatex/) to typeset some Racket source code.  I would like to have line numbers along the left edge, so that I can refer to them in my document.  However, I haven't yet discovered the option for turning line numbers on.

I suspect I should just switch over to the **listings** package and be done with it, but before I do, I wanted to check with the other LaTeX experts here.

Comment: You could try [the `lineno` pacakge](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lineno).But for typesetting source code the `listings` package is the one to use.

Comment: Personally I use `listings`, but an alternative that seems to be gaining some popularity is `minted`, which uses [pygments](http://pygments.org/). That may be worth a look for you. I do recommend moving away from SLaTeX, whichever route you take.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the listings documentation:

> SLaTeX is a pretty-printing Scheme program (which invokes LaTeX
>   automatically) especially designed for Scheme and other Lisp dialects.
>   It supports stand alone ﬁles, text and display listings, and you can
>   even nest the commands/environments if you use LATEX code in comments,
>   for example. Keywords, constants, variables, and symbols are deﬁnable
>   and use of diﬀerent styles is possible. **No line numbers**.

Your best bet, is to use `listings` or `pygments`. Here is a MWE for `listings` to get you going.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\begin{document} 
\lstloadlanguages{Lisp}
\newcommand\emphasis[2][red]{\lstset{emph={#2,},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%
\emphasis{x,a}
\lstset{%
        language={[Auto]Lisp},  
        framesep=0pt,
        numbers=left,numberstyle=\normalsize,stepnumber=1,numbersep=5pt,
        breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{maroon},
    commentstyle=\color{black},
    rulecolor=\color{gray!10},
    xleftmargin=5pt,
    xrightmargin=5pt,
    aboveskip=\bigskipamount,
    belowskip=\bigskipamount,
        backgroundcolor=\color{gray!5}
}
\begin{lstlisting} 
(define-syntax setq 
  (syntax-rules () 
    [(setq x a) 
     (begin (set! x a) 
            x)])) 
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I particularly like about listings (especially if you writing tutorials), is that you can highlight specific key words (see the `\emphasis` macro in the code).

If you actually and absolutely insist that you use SLaTeX, yo can try the following code, which will number the *full page*.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\makeatletter
 \newsavebox{\@linebox}
 \savebox{\@linebox}[3em][t]{\parbox[t]{3em}{%
   \@tempcnta\@ne\relax
   \loop{\underline{\scriptsize\the\@tempcnta}}\\
     \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta<48\repeat}}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyfoot{}
 \fancyhead[CO]{\scriptsize How to Count Lines}
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\thepage}
%% insert this block within a conditional
 \fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\thepage\begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-26,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
      \end{picture}}
 \fancyhead[LO]{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-18,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
     \end{picture}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize Draft copy}
%% end conditional
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
$$f_{nk}=\sum\,{\frac{n!}{
1!^{k_1}\,k_1!\,2!^{k_2}\,k_2!\,3!^{k_3}\,k_3!\,\ldots}}\; 
f_1^{k_1}f_2^{k_2}f_3^{k_3}\ldots\;,$$
summed over all $k_1,k_2,k_3,\ldots\geq 0$ 
\lipsum[3]
$$f_{nk}=\sum\,{\frac{n!}{
1!^{k_1}\,k_1!\,2!^{k_2}\,k_2!\,3!^{k_3}\,k_3!\,\ldots}}\; 
f_1^{k_1}f_2^{k_2}f_3^{k_3}\ldots\;,$$
summed over all $k_1,k_2,k_3,\ldots\geq 0$ 
\lipsum[5-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]